# How to use Admob with phonegap in android

Tags: android, cordova, admob

I am facing trouble in displaying Ads in my Phonegap App, as getting the error message - "***you must have adactivity declared in androidmanifest.xml with configchanges***"

Here is my manifest.xml file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.MyApp"
  android:versionCode="5"
  android:versionName="1.3.1" >

 <supports-screens
  android:largestWidthLimitDp="320"
  android:smallScreens="true"
  android:normalScreens="true"
  android:largeScreens="true"        
  android:xlargeScreens="true"/>


 <uses-sdk

    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

 <application
    android:debuggable="false"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/desktop_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

   <activity
      android:name="com.MyApp.Activity"
      android:label="@string/app_name" 
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|locale">

    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!--      AdMobActivity definition -->

    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize"/>

  </application>


</manifest>
```

The library that I have used for using Admob is ***GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar***

The similar code is working in normal activity (without using phonegap), but facing trouble while embedding admob in phonegap.

Answer (score 5):

This should solve your problem https://github.com/sainttex/PhoneGap-Android-Native-AdMob

Comment: Both links are broken

Answer (score 1):

old version admob sdk is not supported by android .you can try use other plugins.
ref:https://github.com/admob-google/admob-cordova

#### 1.install admob phonegap plugin

use the cordova command
download the plugin ,then install with local location

```
cordova plugin add c:\phonegap-admob-plugin
```

or install cordova plugin online

```
cordova plugin add com.admob.plugin
```

use the phonegap command
download the plugin ,then install with local location

```
phonegap plugin add c:\phonegap-admob-plugin
```

use phonegap builder ,add config

```
<gap:plugin name="com.admob.plugin" version="1.0.0" source="plugins.cordova.io"/>
```

#### 2.init admob phonegap plugin

init plugin after deviceready event

```
admob.initAdmob("admob banner ID","admob interstitial ID");//admob id format ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx
```

#### 3.show banner  at relation position

there are some banner size in admob.BannerSize,and you can create your own banner size that is available in admob platform.
admob.Position hold all relation position const .

```
admob.showBanner(admob.BannerSize.BANNER,admob.Position.TOP_APP);//show banner at the top of app
```

and more you can set more param for admob such as test mode and is your app made for child.

    `var admobParam=new  admob.Params();
        //admobParam.extra={'keyword':"admob phonegame"};
        //admobParam.isForChild=true;
        admobParam.isTesting=true;
        admob.showBanner(admob.BannerSize.BANNER,admob.Position.TOP_CENTER,admobParam);`

#### 4.show banner  at absolute position

you can put admob banner at absolute position as easy as relation position.

```
admob.showBannerAbsolute(admob.BannerSize.BANNER,0,70);//show banner at absolute position x 0,y 70
```

#### 5.show admob Interstitial

show admob Interstitial in phonegap,cordova or xdk application is the same step.
cache Interstitial ,and then show it in onInterstitialReceive function or show it when your game over.
```

```
document.addEventListener(admob.Event.onInterstitialReceive, onInterstitialReceive, false);//show in ad receive event fun need add receive listener
 admob.cacheInterstitial();// load admob Interstitial
 function onInterstitialReceive(message) {//show in ad receive event fun
     admob.showInterstitial();
 }
 function onGameOver(){//call this fun to show when game over
        admob.isInterstitialReady(function(isReady){
            if(isReady){
                admob.showInterstitial();
            }
        });
  }
```

```

#### 6.handle admob ad event

you can handler all native event of admob ,as onInterstitialReceive 
all event type is in admob.Event
```

```
function onAdmobEvent (message) {
    //do some on admob event
}
document.addEventListener(admob.Event.onAdmobBannerDismiss, onAdmobEvent, false);
document.addEventListener(admob.Event.onAdmobBannerFailedReceive), onAdmobEvent, false);
document.addEventListener(admob.Event.onAdmobBannerLeaveApplication), onAdmobEvent, false);
document.addEventListener(admob.Event.onAdmobBannerPresent), onAdmobEvent, false);
document.addEventListener(admob.Event.onAdmobBannerReceive), onAdmobEvent, false);
document.addEventListener(admob.Event.onAdmobInterstitialDismiss), onAdmobEvent, false);
document.addEventListener(admob.Event.onAdmobInterstitialFailedReceive), onAdmobEvent, false);
document.addEventListener(admob.Event.onAdmobInterstitialLeaveApplication), onAdmobEvent, false);
document.addEventListener(admob.Event.onAdmobInterstitialPresent), onAdmobEvent, false);
document.addEventListener(admob.Event.onAdmobInterstitialReceive), onAdmobEvent, false);
```

```

#### 7.more function

1.hide admob banner

```
admob.hideBanner()
```

2.test if Interstitial has loaded success
```

```
admob.isInterstitialReady(function(isReady){
    if(isReady){
        alert("admob Interstitial loaded");
    }
});
```

```